# I got some problem

Tags: ros, turtlesim, rosrun, turtlesim-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

dear all,
I want to run a simple example like this

sony@sony-virtual-machine:~$ rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node[ERROR] [1429091431.360422919]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...
what`s wrong with this?

thank you all

Sony

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207150/i-got-some-problem/) by [sony](https://answers.ros.org/users/22164/sony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

open another shell and run:

```
roscore
```

and re-launch your node:

```
rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
```

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2015-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sony](https://answers.ros.org/users/22164/sony/) on 2015-04-22**:
thank you so much!

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2015-04-22**:
Welcome, if it is the right answer you can make it as correct in the left of my answer.. @sony